# How to automatically close a dialogue window in Linux?

Tags: bash, user-interface, automation

I use both qt creator and vim for c++ programming sometimes. When a file is changed in vim, and focus is back on qt creator, 
it prompts me to accept or reject the change made by vim, I choose yes all the time.

There is no option, as far as I know, in qt creator to accept without prompting the user, so I created a bash script to address this issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
    mywinprop=$(xprop -id ${myw})
    if [[ \
        $(echo "$mywinprop" | egrep 'NET_WM_NAME.*File Changed') && \
        $(echo "$mywinprop" | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*qtcreator') \
        ]]
    then
        xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\r" >/dev/null 2>&1
    else
        sleep 0.5
    fi
done
```

It works ok, the prompt dialogue appears and then quickly disappears, but it's still annoying. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. (I have submitted a feature request already, not sure they will implement this, though.)

The solution is potentially applicable in many similar situations.

Comment: I like your solution ;) But: you should not edit the same file with two different editors at the same time.

Comment: even if you change something in Qt Creator, and focus back to vim, it would ask you to reload, this should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, you've done almost the max - Qt Creator is open source and you can develop your own patch for the behavior you want  (which you can then submit for upstream they'll likely be more receptive to a well developed patch then to a suggestion that they should develop a patch) and build Qt Creator for your own use with your custom patched behavior.

Assuming this is too much work (it sounds like it to me), I can only recommend a small improvement on your workflow - have the window manager not show the "File Changed" dialog. Kwin on Plasma has a rule system exactly for that kind of things, or you can use Devilspie on GNOME on X11 (atm there's no such functionality for GNOME on Wayland).